How to sum values based on unique values in other column when filter is applied
I have the following problem. There are order numbers in column A which are duplicated due to a different products in column B. What I need is to sum order values in column C only for unique order numbers when filter is applied.
Hereby some screenshots:



Could you guys please help me?
Thanks in advance

Try using the following formula:


=SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A14,C2:C14),MAP(D2:D14,LAMBDA(α,SUBTOTAL(103,α))))),,1))


When Manager Peter is selected:


When Country France is selected:



You're a star! This works just perfect. Thank you very much for you help! Highly appreciated.

@ZuzanaHošová please ensure to accept the answer by ticking the checkmark beside it
